# Download File from website without filename? Python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, request

I dont know where to exactly start here, and I have to admit my knowledge of python and websites are limited.  However In the past ive done some requests from an api and accessed a file or two from a website but I had some examples to build off of.  In this case I have no written example to help me through the process so I dont really know where to start or if "requests" is even the way to go.

What I have is a distributor's website that has a file with product information.
If I were to download this file manually I would have to login, navigate to the download section of the website.  At this point a popup appears where I select the brand I want to download, I have options to select from as far as data I would like to gather, a text box to name the file and a download button that has no url.

Im sure all this seems pretty vague since I dont know what info would be helpful at this point.

A nudge in the right direct would be great!!
Thanks
[Screen shot of popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hz9CE.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like there may not be an API, in instances like this using a web automation solution such as [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) could get you the desired result.

For your case it sounds like you will need to [find the button elements](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html) and then [click them](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.click)

From their basic example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.send_keys("pycon")
enter code here`elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

based on your example html code, after you load the page, you could use the following to find the button and click it

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("downloadBtn")
elem.click()
```

Comment: Dont know if this helps but this is the download button
<button id="downloadBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="requestType" value="brandExportSplash">Download</button>

Comment: Well it took a few days to get it all figured out but this worked great.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: great, this is a very useful tool to have in your toolbelt

Answer (score 0):

You can use a http library like [Request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to download this. but you may offer the username and password, you can study from its examples.

Answer (score 0):

If the site you wish to download from has no JavaScript you will need to parse to navigate to the file you wish, consider using [RoboBrowser](http://robobrowser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Selenium may be overkill for  this.

Here is a basic example:

```
robo = RoboBrowser(history=True, parser="html.parser")
robo.open("http://www.python.org")
search = robo.get_form(action="/search/")
search["q"].value = "Really awesome search query"
robo.submit_form(search)
```